# What is the name of this expression?

Tags: factorial

I'm trying to search this expression online, but don't know what it's called:

$$\frac{n!}{n^x(n-x)!} = \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right) \cdots \left(1-\frac{x-1}{n}\right)$$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is $x$ an integer between $0$ and $n$?

Comment: Ahh, you changed this after I had first read it!
But it is still **not** true!  For example if n= x= 1 then the left side is $\frac{1!}{1^1(0!)}= 1$ while the right side is $(1- 1)(1)= 0$.

Comment: This isn't quite relevant, but it is close:  you could rewrite part of the expression in terms of [the Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials), and I wonder if [(generalized) hypergeometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) by be related.

Answer (score 3):

If $x$ is an integer between $0$ and $n$, then that equality follows direct from the definitions. It has no special name.
$$
(1-\frac{1}{n})(1-\frac{2}{n})\cdots(1-\frac{x-1}{n})
=\frac{(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-x+1)}{n^{x-1}}
\\=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-x+1)}{n^{x}}
=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-x+1)(n-x)!}{n^{x}(n-x)!}
=\frac{n!}{n^x(n-x)!}
$$

Comment: Okay, thank you for your answer.